# Strange django output

Tags: python, django

I've installed transifex - django application. Everything looked ok, but if I run:

```
./manage runserver 8000
```

I got error message (below). Since I'm inexpedience django user supposedly it is some easy error/mistake. Unfortunately, I'm unable to discover what the problem is.
Any clue will is appreciated!
Thanks, Tomas

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'staticfiles',
 'notification',
 'django_filters',
 'django_sorting',
 'south',
 'tagging',
 'tagging_autocomplete',
 'pagination',
 'piston',
 'contact_form',
 'ajax_select',
 'threadedcomments',
 'authority',
 'haystack',
 'social_auth',
 'userena',
 'guardian',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'djcelery',
 'djkombu',
 'compressor',
 'transifex.txcommon',
 'transifex.languages',
 'transifex.projects',
 'transifex.releases',
 'transifex.actionlog',
 'transifex.txpermissions',
 'transifex.teams',
 'transifex.resources',
 'django_addons',
 'autofetch',
 'charts',
 'cla',
 'copyright',
 'datastores',
 'gtranslate',
 'helptext',
 'jsonmap',
 'locks',
 'lotte',
 'priorities',
 'suggestions',
 'timeline',
 'trans_memory',
 'txapps',
 'txcron',
 'txtestsuite',
 'watches',
 'webhooks',
 'widgets']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django_sorting.middleware.SortingMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
 'userena.middleware.UserenaLocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers    /base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django   /core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django   /core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transifex-1.3.0devel-py2.7.egg/transifex/addons/cla/urls.py" in <module>
  2. from transifex.projects.urls import PROJECT_URL
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transifex-1.3.0devel-py2.7.egg/transifex/projects/urls/__init__.py" in <module>
  6. from transifex.projects.feeds import LatestProjects, ProjectFeed,    ProjectTimelineFeed
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transifex-1.3.0devel-py2.7.egg/transifex/projects/feeds.py" in <module>
  11. current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
  25.             current_site = self.get(pk=sid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  349.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: just to highlight the problem: error message in browser is:  "DoesNotExist at \"

Comment: I think, you should provide `SITE_ID` in your `settings.py`. Also you need a site instance to be on your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all run `python manage.py syncdb`. Then check this query in django shell:

```
Site.objects.get(id=1)
```

if `DoesNotExist` error is raised create `Site` object manually:

```
Site.objects.create(name='example.com', domain='example.com')
```

Comment: thanks! even I run `manage.py syncdb` without error message something went wrong. I re-run the command and everything was OK - thanks a lot!